# Can you get the AWS MFA serial number programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-iam

Using the AWS .NET SDK.
I am able query AWS using the locally stored SDK profiles.
Some accounts need to be accessed using a cross account role.
When using the SDK to assume a role I have to supply the MFA serial number.
Is there any way to get that serial number from the account using the SDK profile?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to helloV I figured out some code that works.

```
AWSCredentials creds = new StoredProfileAWSCredentials(Profile_CBB.Text);
Amazon.IdentityManagement.AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient imc = new Amazon.IdentityManagement.AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(creds);
Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.ListMFADevicesRequest mfaRequest = new Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.ListMFADevicesRequest();
Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.ListMFADevicesResponse mfaResponse = imc.ListMFADevices(mfaRequest);
```